Скрыть ответы в Googl form
В Google Form у меня около 30 ответов. При заполнение всех ответов возникает ошибка достижение максимального количество символов в Discord.
Решение упростить отображение ответов.
if (B11 != 0){
discordPayload.embeds[0].fields.push({ name: "Тренировке:", value: B11+" "+B11a })}

Остался вопрос как скрыть все ответы из GOOGLE FORM ?
То есть что бы они не приходили дубликатом в вебхук дискорда
